# Zend variable not accessible in view

Tags: zend-framework, view

I have my own abstract class that extends Zend_Controller_Action and all my controllers then extend this class. Here is my abstract class:

```
<?php
abstract class CLG_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{
public $admin;
public $staff;
public $pool;
public $it;
//public $staff;

/**
 * 
 * @var HTMLPurifier
 */
public $purifier;

public $action;
public $controller;

public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array())
{
    parent::__construct($request, $response, $invokeArgs);

    if( Zend_Registry::isRegistered('admin') ) {
        $this->admin = Zend_Registry::get('admin');

    }
    if( Zend_Registry::isRegistered('staff') ) {
        $this->staff = Zend_Registry::get('staff');
    }
    if( Zend_Registry::isRegistered('pool') ) {
        $this->pool = Zend_Registry::get('pool');
    }

    $this->purifier = Zend_Registry::get('purifier');

    $this->controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
    $this->action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $this->registerViewObjects();           
}

public function postDispatch() 
{
    /************************************************
     * Prepare JS and CSS FILES FOR THIS REQUEST
     ************************************************/
    $action     = $this->_request->getActionName();
    $controller = $this->_request->getControllerName();

    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js');

    if (key_exists ( $this->_request->getActionName (), $this->assets )) 
    {
        $action = $this->_request->getActionName ();

        foreach ( $this->assets [$action] ['css'] as $css ) 
        {
            $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet ( $css , 'print');
        }
        foreach ( $this->assets [$action] ['js'] as $js ) 
        {
            $this->view->headScript()->appendFile( $js );
        }
    }

    $css = '/css/' . $controller . '/' . $action . '.css';
    $js = '/js/' . $controller . '/' . $action . '.js';

    $this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet ( $css , 'print');
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile( $js );   
}

private function registerViewObjects()
{
    // THESE ARE ALWAYS AVAILABLE IN THE VIEW
    $this->view->admin = $this->admin;
    $this->view->staff = $this->staff;
    $this->view->pool = $this->pool;
    $this->view->controller = $this->controller;
    $this->view->action = $this->action;
    $this->view->purifier = $this->purifier;    
}
```

}

However, for some reason, the variables registered in the registerViewObjects() are not accessible in my view files.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

UPDATE:
I should say that I have another class ActionMenu that extends Action, and my controllers then extend that class!

Comment: Are you sure that `ActionMenu::__construct()` is calling the `parent::__construct()`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using __construct over init()? I'm pretty sure this is the reason of your problem because Zend performs various actions regarding the request, action etc in the __construct() stage.

```
/**
 * @return void 
 */    
public function init()
{
    if( Zend_Registry::isRegistered('admin') ) {
        $this->admin = Zend_Registry::get('admin');

    }
    if( Zend_Registry::isRegistered('staff') ) {
        $this->staff = Zend_Registry::get('staff');
    }
    if( Zend_Registry::isRegistered('pool') ) {
        $this->pool = Zend_Registry::get('pool');
    }

    $this->purifier = Zend_Registry::get('purifier');

    $this->controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
    $this->action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $this->registerViewObjects();     
}
```

See also:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.initialization

Comment: I changed it to init() but still no change.

Comment: And you are 100% positive that admin, staff & pool are set (if you do a var_dump(Zend_Registry::get('admin'));die; on the first line of the public init function, do you get any values?

Comment: Yes 100%. admin, pool, staff are accessible in the controllers. Just not in the view.

Comment: So if you, for example, test $this->view->admin = Zend_Registry::get('admin'); and comment out the registerViewObjects you get a value in your view?

Comment: Yes, if I do that in the action of my page it works. I can even do $this->view->admin = $this->admin and it works!

Comment: I have no further clues; If it's a regular php action controller the init() example I provided 100% works. Probably the problem is in your extended class construction. Test it with a vanilla controller to see for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as you're attempting to use the `$view` property so early in the controller lifecycle, maybe you just need to initialise it before putting values in, eg

```
private function registerViewObjects() {
    $this->initView();

    // and the rest
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.viewintegration